# local variable not set by calling local method from inherited constructor

Tags: typescript

So I have the following class declarations:

```
abstract class A {
    constructor() {
        console.log("A.constructor() is called.");
        this.foo();
    }
    abstract foo();
}

abstract class B extends A {}

class C extends B {

    private bar = null;

    foo() {
        console.log("C.foo() is called.");
        this.bar = "bar";
    }

    getBar() {
        console.log("C.getBar() is called.");
        return this.bar;
    }

}
```

Now I try to call this by doing the following:

```
let x = new C();
console.log(x.getBar());
```

Here is the output:

```
A.constructor() is called.
C.foo() is called.
C.getBar() is called.
null
```

I have the same exact code but in PHP and it works correctly. Can any one please explain what am I missing?

Thanks in advance,
Ramon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Ts will be compile to JS like snippet above, I memo some points in the code.

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        console.log("A.constructor() is called.");
        this.foo(); // 2. Set `this.bar = "bar"` => Ok
        // You can check bar value by add a `console.log(this.bar)` here
    }
}
class B extends A {
}
class C extends B {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments); // 1. A constructor has been call at first
        this.bar = null; // 3. `bar` value has been `reset` to `null`
    }
    foo() {
        console.log("C.foo() is called.");
        this.bar = "bar";
    }
    getBar() {
        console.log("C.getBar() is called.");
        return this.bar;
    }
}
let x = new C();
console.log(x.getBar());
```

Comment: This is actually what I also came up with. I was just wondering why it worked as-is in PHP and not in TS/JS.

The more I look at it, however, the more I realise that the JS one seems like the correct thing to look at even though the PHP one actually follows the "template method pattern".

Calling child method in parent constructor just seems like a sinful thing to do. I guess I just got spoiled by PHP.

Thanks for the answer.